# Access Pelican page and article metadata the same way?

Tags: jinja2, pelican

I currently have this part in my `base.html` Pelican template:

```
{% if article and article.author %}
<meta name="author" content="{{ article.author }}" />
<meta name="copyright" content="{{ article.author }}" />
{% elif page and page.author %}
<meta name="author" content="{{ page.author }}" />
<meta name="copyright" content="{{ page.author }}" />
{% else %}
<meta name="author" content="{{ AUTHOR }}" />
<meta name="copyright" content="{{ AUTHOR }}" />
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to simplify this, e.g. something like

```
<meta name="author" content="{{ publication.author }}" />
<meta name="copyright" content="{{ publication.author }}" />
```

where publication is either `page` or `article`? (I guess it is never possible that something is both, a page and an article?)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
{% if article.author %} {% set author = article.author %}
{% elif page.author %} {% set author = page.author %}
{% else %} {% set author = AUTHOR %} {% endif %}

{% if page or article %}
<meta name="author" content="{{ author }}" />
<meta name="copyright" content="{{ author }}" />
{% endif %}
```

You should be able to erase the last "if" because it's not necessary if you put this in blocks which belong to pages or articles.